# Suggest a page template for a specific view

Tags: views, theming

I have a view **news** how do you a suggest a particular theme file for it? For example page--news.tpl.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Views 2, One of the option would be to name your template file "views-view--news.tpl.php".

There are  other useful options like "views-view--news--page.tpl.php" or  "views-view--news--block.tpl.php" depending on your display type.

You may find [This](http://www.group42.ca/theming_views_2_the_basics) tutorial useful .